# loading an image on web browser using Promise()

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, es6-promise

I'am trying to learn how to make SuperMario in JavaScript from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-FpDQ8Eqw8&list=PLS8HfBXv9ZWWe8zXrViYbIM2Hhylx8DZx)
Can someone explain flow of the below function LoadImage ?

```
function loadImage(url) {
        return new  Promise(resolve => {
            const image = new Image();
            image.addEventListener('load', () => {
                resolve(image);
            });
            image.src = url; 
        });
}

const canvas = document.getElementById('screen');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.fillRect(0,0,50,50);

loadImage('/img/tiles.png')
.then(image=>{
    context.drawImage(image,0,0);  // the function LoadImage returns a Promise with image object(which is  a constant)
// as parameter and if the promise is fulfilled then the image is drawn. 
/
});
```

**EDIT**

I do understand how to use => operator. 
Which is used to make length of functions smaller.

```
image.addEventListener('load', () => {
                resolve(image);
```

the above line means that the promise is fulfilled when image is loaded.
So does this mean that the following line is executed and then the event listener is waiting for the image to be downloaded in client browser ?

```
image.scr = url;
```

The flow of the below function is a little fuzzy to me

```
function loadImage(url) {
        return new  Promise(resolve => {
            const image = new Image();
            image.addEventListener('load', () => {
                resolve(image);
            });
            image.src = url; 
        });
```

EDIT 2:

Okay, this was a stupid post. And yup as the IMAGE from url is loaded in the image object then Event listener fires up the resolve().

Comment: Please add to your question what you *think* the code does as well as what particular part of the code you don't understand.  As it stands right now, your question is too broad per the meta: [“Explain X to me” questions: How to react?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271468/691711).

Comment: Alright i understand you. I've edited the post and tried to explain my problem best as i can.

Comment: Which is used to make length of functions smaller. — That isn't what it is for. It binds `this`.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The code you are showing introduces an asynchronous primitive, Promise, which can be passed around and used to access a resource that hasn't been populated yet.

In this case, you want an `Image` that is fully loaded and has image data that you can use.  However, you can't access the image data until a network request finishes that would fetch the image data.

For example, this won't work:

```js
const img = new Image();
img.src = "example.com/house.jpg";
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); // img isn't done loading yet
```

Instead, we have to **wait** until the loading is done.  There are a lot of ways to do that but the most common conventions are to use, callbacks, Promises, or async/await.

The method that you have shown combines callbacks and Promises (out of necessity).

Let's break down the code:

```js
/**
 * Load an image from a given URL
 * @param {String} url The URL of the image resource
 * @returns {Promise<Image>} The loaded image
 */
function loadImage(url) {
  /*
   * We are going to return a Promise which, when we .then
   * will give us an Image that should be fully loaded
   */
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    /*
     * Create the image that we are going to use to
     * to hold the resource
     */
    const image = new Image();
    /*
     * The Image API deals in even listeners and callbacks
     * we attach a listener for the "load" event which fires
     * when the Image has finished the network request and
     * populated the Image with data
     */
    image.addEventListener('load', () => {
      /*
       * You have to manually tell the Promise that you are
       * done dealing with asynchronous stuff and you are ready
       * for it to give anything that attached a callback
       * through .then a realized value.  We do that by calling
       * resolve and passing it the realized value
       */
      resolve(image);
    });
    /*
     * Setting the Image.src is what starts the networking process
     * to populate an image.  After you set it, the browser fires
     * a request to get the resource.  We attached a load listener
     * which will be called once the request finishes and we have
     * image data
     */
    image.src = url;
  });
}

/*
 * To use this we call the loadImage function and call .then
 * on the Promise that it returns, passing a function that we
 * want to receive the realized Image
 */
loadImage("example.com/house.jpg").then(houseImage => {
  ctx.drawImage(houseImage, 0, 0);
});
```

---

In all honesty though, the `loadImage` function could be a little bit more robust since it doesn't handle errors right now.  Consider the following enhancement:

```js
const loadImage = (url) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(img));
  img.addEventListener('error', (err) => reject(err));
  img.src = url;
});

loadImage("example.com/house.jpg")
  .then(img => console.log(`w: ${img.width} | h: ${img.height}`))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: The way i framed my question was unreadable. I didn't expect any answers but you sir took some time out of you life to Answer my question. I've gained new knowledge today. Thank you.

Comment: That's a comprehensive answer. Well done. One small note though, in `img.addEventListener("error", err => reject(err));` no need for the arrow func, `img.addEventListener("error", reject);` is enough.

Comment: If i use this code to add image backgrounds in my page, will this increase efficiency of my page

Comment: @ankit I would just let the CSS background image property do it. There would probably no significant difference one way or the other.

Comment: Best answer for the whole "Promise resolve", didn't upvote cause you're at 69 now :)

Answer (score 7):

A compressed/short example:

```js
let url = "https://example.com/image.png";
let img = new Image();
await new Promise(r => {img.onload=r; img.src=url});
// now do something with img
```

Comment: What is this form of arrow functions: r => doOneThing, doAnotherThing? I mean the "normal" form is r => {doOneThing; doAnotherThing}. Why a comma and not the semicolon?

Comment: @PhilippeOceangermanique Yep, it's the same thing in this case. The comma just allows us to omit the curly brackets, making the example a tiny bit shorter. I should probably have just used semicolon and curly braces for clarity. See this question for more details on differences between comma and semicolon: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15485846/11950764

Comment: The comma expression is confusing to read so I would never use it in production code, but it's valid JavaScript and certainly thought-provoking.

Comment: @RobertPenner Yeah you're right - I've just swapped it for normal curly bracket notation to reduce confusion. I should have done this from the start.