# how to lazy load images from array using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I get a json response from a simple API I made,it contains thousands of image urls and sizes around 1.7MB. I am not using any JS framework/libraries. So, what would be efficient way to load the images in DOM?

Comment: How JSON structure is? Do you need loading or "lazy" (random?) loading? Your question is not clear.

Comment: suppose its a large list of urls containing images, I will be running this in localhost, I don't care about order or accessibility or anything, just that it takes too long to load all at once. so I was looking for simples solution. and I found it.

Comment: It's clearer now. _Lazy loading_ could be the solution, but keep in mind that it's not supported by all browsers: https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get this done by including lazy load to your image tag by setting the loading to "lazy"
This is the simplest solution I know, no js required

```
<img src="your-images-url-goes-here.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="..." />
```

The loading attribute gives us the option to delay off-screen images and iframes until users scroll to their location on the page. loading can take any of these three values:

lazy: works great for lazy loading
eager: instructs the browser to load the specified content right away
auto: leaves the option to lazy load or not to lazy load up to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should populate the array with Promise objects which will display some default value at first (a local default-blank.png with a loading spinner for instance, it's up to you) and then, once the promise is solved, you should trigger a callback which will repopulate the object with the externally loaded image.

This can be easily accomplished with vanilla JS. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059596/loading-an-image-on-web-browser-using-promise/52060802) answer, it describes in detail how to do so.