# Loading an image using the Fetch API for use with WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I want to load textures without callbacks like `.onload()`. I am trying to use texture from blob: https://plnkr.co/edit/n4CbWMEOAyJMQFYy

```js
    const response = await fetch("./assets/texture.png");
    const imageBlob = await response.blob();
    const imageBitmap = await createImageBitmap(imageBlob);
    console.log(imageBitmap);

    const texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageBitmap);
```

Expected result is:

[image]

But I have this:

[image]

I can see in the `Network` tab that the image has been uploaded:

[image]

This line of code `console.log(imageBitmap);` says that the image exists:

[image]

`texImage2D()` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D) says that I can use ImageBitmap as source.

*Updated*

I tried to use the `loadImage` function from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52060802/4159530 Playground: https://plnkr.co/edit/n4CbWMEOAyJMQFYy

```js
function loadImage(url) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resolve(image);
        });
        image.src = url;
    });
}

/* ... */

async function init() {
/* ... */

    const image = await loadImage("./assets/texture.png");
    const texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

/* ... */
}
```

But that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I haven't used the `response.blob()` mechanism, but I have had success using `Image()`.  Can you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52060802/691711?  Maybe the way the blob is formed is causing issues.  I think `Image()` may also do the handling of the encoding but I might be making assumptions there.

Comment: Unfortunately `loadImage()` doesn't work: `const image = await loadImage("./assets/texture.png");`

Comment: @zero298 I added to my post what I tried on your advice.

Comment: @zero298 You can try it on Playground: https://plnkr.co/edit/n4CbWMEOAyJMQFYy

Comment: @zero298 now it works! I added `draw();` after `gl.texImage2D`: https://plnkr.co/edit/n4CbWMEOAyJMQFYy But I don't understand why is this `draw()` function being skipped: ```function main() {
    if (!init()) return;
    draw();
}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer helped me to solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52060802/4159530

Playground: https://plnkr.co/edit/n4CbWMEOAyJMQFYy

```js
function loadImage(url) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.addEventListener("load", () => {
            resolve(image);
        });
        image.src = url;
    });
}

/* ... */

async function init() {
/* ... */

    const image = await loadImage("./assets/texture.png");
    const texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    draw();

/* ... */
}
```

As you can see, I call the `draw()` function after the `gl.texImage2D()` function. I don't understand why this `draw()` function is skipped:

```js
function main() {
    if (!init()) return;
    draw();
}
```

**Added 7/27/2023**. I use this code to load textures and shaders using Fetch API (async/await): https://plnkr.co/edit/KaDgu8R6NJxnDEbO?preview

load-texture.js

```js
import { gl } from "./webgl-context.js";

export default function loadTexture(url, minType = gl.NEAREST, magType = gl.NEAREST) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.onload = () => {
            const texture = gl.createTexture();
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, minType);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, magType);
            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
            resolve(texture);
        };
        image.src = url;
    });
}
```

index.js

```
async function init() {
    const texture = await loadTexture("./assets/textures/texture.png",
        gl.LINEAR, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
}

init();
```

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here][1]Loading Imagebitmap in gl.texImage2D() method works only in webgl2.
var gl = someCanvas.getContext("webgl2");

It is working for me.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgGPz.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).