# More FileReader readAsText() async typescript issues?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filereader

So I'm having similar issues to the person [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51026420/filereader-readastext-async-issues); however, after implementing the changes it still isn't working as intended.

Essentially, the update function is called whenever the file-directory input receives an input. What I want to happen is to iteratively read through each file and store the text to a property in an angular service class. The problem is, even after implementing the promise and telling the update function to await the readFile, it doesn't wait and goes onto the next iteration of the forloop.

The For each loop ends up calling this.readFile(file,last) for each file first and then after it has gone through every file, it then console.log("next") for each file.

```
update(event){
console.log( event.target.files[0])
this.files = Array.from(event.target.files)


try{
  this.files.forEach(async (file,index) => {
    let last = index == this.files.length-1
    await this.readFile(file,last)
    console.log("next")
  })
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

}

```
readFile(file,last:boolean){
let tempName = "_"+file.name
let reg = /\./
tempName = tempName.replace(reg,'_')


// Always return a Promise
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  if(this.fileService.hasOwnProperty(tempName)){
    const reader = new FileReader();
      
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.fileService[tempName] = (reader.result).toString()
      if(last)
        this.next()
      resolve(true)
      
    }
    reader.onerror = function(e: any) {
      reject(e);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file)
  } else {
    this.fileService.failedPaths.push(file)
    if(last)
        this.next()
    resolve(false)
  }

});}
```

HTML File Input

```
<input id="file_input" [(ngModel)]="value" (change)="update($event)" type="file" webkitdirectory
                directory />
```

Comment: There is no waiting happening from the perspective of the forEach. What you need is to use `for of` and having the async context start outside already.

Comment: just use `file.text()` instead of using the FileReader